# How to save static data and apply filter at the time of getting product list from database in c# mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I want to store this below static data into my project. i don't want to store it into database.

**Category** table:

```
id Name
---------------------
1  Electronic
2  Baby Kids
3  Home & Furniture
```

**Sub_Category** table

```
id name    categoryId
---------------------
1  Mobile  1
2  Laptop  1
3  care    2
4  Toys    2
```

Now this above table store into database but i need to store it into my project as static so no one can modify it.

How many way to store it?

This store data is also use when product list come from database at the time I need to filter this product list with my static data.

I try to store using class and `enum` but when I need to use this data, product list come from database but I unable to filter product using my static data.

I want to apply this filter using stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating Class Category of type List and at the time of class initialization (probably in Constructor) you can assign static values.

```
public class Category
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class SubCategory
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public int CategoryId {get;set;}
}
```